# Parameters to decrease the retrieval of key-value pairs in Vault

Tags: consul, hashicorp-vault

I have a cluster which consists of three Vaults and another cluster of three Consuls which serves as the storage back-end. The nodes are configured with the basic configuration to form a cluster and each node is hosted on one VM. 
I have performed some fail-over tests and when Vault active is down, to retrieve the key-value pair is taking around 35 seconds, which is quite a lot.

I have tried to add in the Consul configuration `"session_ttl_min: 2s"` to decrease the time of retrieving the password, but I couldn't notice any change.

It's any other parameters which can be set to retrieve faster the key-value pairs and to decrease the fail-over timeout?

I am using Vault v1.1.1 and Consul v1.4.4 versions.